# Python cannot iterate a list completely

Tags: list, python-2.7, debugging, for-loop, iteration

So I posted this before but I didn't follow the community guidelines so I decided to post it again this time following the community guidelines. (I tried to delete my other question but it wouldn't let me)

Here is the minimal amount of code I could do to create the same problem:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)

        self.inventory = []

        try: self.itemComponent.owner = self
        except: self.itemComponent = None

class Item:
    def drop(self):
        for obj in objects:
            if self.owner in obj.inventory:
                objects.append(self.owner)
                obj.inventory.remove(self.owner)

def monster_death(monster):
    monster.name = 'Goblin Corpse'
    for element in monster.inventory:
        if element.itemComponent:
            element.itemComponent.drop()

objects = []

#Create Goblin
monster = Object(name = 'Goblin')

#Populate Goblin's Equipment
monster.inventory = [
    Object(name='Dagger', itemComponent=Item() ),
    Object(name='Light Healing Potion', itemComponent=Item() ),
    Object(name='Scroll of Chain Lightning', itemComponent=Item())
]

objects.append(monster)

print '=~In Monster Inventory~='
for item in monster.inventory:
    print item.name

print
print '=~In World~='
for obj in objects:
    print obj.name

print
print '***MONSTER DIES***'
print
monster_death(monster)

print '=~In Monster Inventory~='
print
for item in monster.inventory:
    print item.name

print
print '=~In World~='
print
for obj in objects:
    print obj.name
```

What happens is one of the items always stays in the monsters inventory...it seems almost random which item stays in but it is always the same item every time unless I remove or add more items to his inventory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing from the list that you are currently iterating through, that will affect the iteration.

If you need to process each item, then do that in the loop, and then clear the list afterwards

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_list[:] = [] # clear the list without replacing it
```

Comment: That was it. I fixed it in a different way than you described I saved a temp variable with the size of the list and then just removed the 0th element out of the list for that many iterations and it worked. :)